# Servlet works on debug mode but fails to work when deployed to AppEngine (Appspot)

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have a gwt application that have some servlet on it. During development mode, the servlet can be accessed properly but when deployed I can't access it like:

Debug mode:
`http://127.0.0.1:8888/mygwtapp/greet` (Works)

Deployed in Appspot.com
`http://mygwtapp123456.appspot.com/mygwtapp/greet` (Does not work)

What could be the problem?

Here's the mapping on the web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mygwtapp.server.GreetServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mygwtapp/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: "Does not work" is unhelpful. What happens when you try? Does it throw a 500? If so, what do the logs say? Does your monitor start smoking? Do tigers leap out of the shadows and maul you? Give us a clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you using `http://mygwtapp123456.appspot.com/mygwtapp/greet` when deployed, when this is what you mapped in your web.xml?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. I'm using http://mygwtapp123456.appspot.com/mygwtapp/greet

Comment: Also, I revied the logs from my Appengine web panel I see this warning: No handlers matched this URL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've updated your default version in appengine control panel?  If you updated version id in appengine-web.xml, but haven't set that as default, your appspot could be serving a web.xml that doesn't have your updated servlet.

If this is not the issue, please respond with any additional logging / error messages you encounter.